# Динамическое приведение типа

Tags: c#, unity3d

Никак не могу разобраться с приведениями типов.

Написал метод:

```
public static Transform Transform(GameObject Object, string Name) {
     Transform tm = Object.transform;
     for (int i = 0; i < tm.childCount; ++i) {
         Transform child = tm.GetChild(i);
         if (child.name.Equals(Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
             return child;
         }
     }
     return null;
}
```

Смотрит нужный мне объект, в дереве родителя.
И мне захотелось сделать так, чтобы можно было через передачу нужного типа `<T>`  привести к этому типу, который передали.

Написал также такой код:

```
private T Transform<T>(string Name) {
    Transform trans = С.Transform(Obj, Name); // это метод выше
    return Transform<T>(trans.gameObject);
}

public static T Transform<T>(object input, T defaultValue) {
    return null == input ? defaultValue : (T)Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(T));
}

public static T Transform<T>(object input) {
    return Transform(input, default(T));
}
```

Но начало выбивать:

> InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.

Чисто для себя интересно, как такое сделать.

А так, конечно можно использовать:

```
Button Name = Transform(obj, "Name").GetComponent<Button>();
```

Но хочется понять, как сделать именно вот так:

```
Button Name = Transform<Button>("Name");
```

И вообще без использования `GetComponent`.

Comment: "И вообще без использования `GetComponent`" - никак. Игровые объекты - контейнеры своих компонентов, по сути, вы спрашиваете, как индексировать массив без метода `.At` или оператора `[]`.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, Я понял, тогда с использованием компонента становится все просто. Я надеялся, что есть какой-то особый метод, который узнает, что это `UI` и вытащит тип из него.

Comment: Ну такую обертку все еще можно написать: `Button Name = Transform<Button>("Name");`.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, Сделайте ответ, я выберу, вам больше пользы будет, чем мне. Даже если я и сам отвечу. Я так то знаю, что будет именно так и работать, просто через `GetComponent<T>` проталкивать тип метода и все. Я думал есть другой способ. Чтобы не задействовать `GetComponent`.

Comment: Ну а по каким меркам то он может это определить? :) Разве что тэги, но поиск по тэгам - это такое себе...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще вариантов несколько, начиная от самого примитивного:

```
public static Transform Transform(GameObject @object, string name) {
    Transform tm = @object.transform;
        for (var child in transform){
            if (child.name == name){
                return child;
            }
        }
    return null;
}

public static T Transform<T>(GameObject @object, string Name) where T : MonoBehaviour {
    return Transform(@object, Name)?.GetComponent<T>() ?? null;
}
```

И заканчивая такой штукой:

```
static public T Transform<T>(GameObject @object, string name) where T : Component {
    T[] childrenWithComponent = @object.transform.GetComponentsInChildren<T>(true);
    foreach (var child in childrenWithComponent){
        if (child.gameObject.name == name){
            return child;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Причем теоретически второй подход будет быстрее, т.к. `GetComponentsInChildren` - функция с нативной стороны, так что вы сначала быстро получаете набор объектов с нужным компонентом, а уже потом по этому ограниченному набору ищете объект с нужным именем. Если во всей иерархии такой объект с таким компонентом один, то это практически гарантированно будет быстрее первого подхода (разве что только если все объекты будут содержать 1 ребенка).

---

**Upd**

Чтобы искать GameObject, а не компонент, нужно либо сделать отдельную реализацию:

```
static public GameObject Transform(GameObject @object, string name) {
    Transform[] childrenWithComponent = @object.transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true);
    foreach (var child in childrenWithComponent){
        if (child.gameObject.name == name){
            return child.gameObject;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Что, по сути, дублирование кода. Можно просто вызывать изначальный метод и получать от него `GameObject`:

```
var trans = Transform<Transform>(gameObject, "name");
var gameObj = Transform<Transform>(gameObject, "name").gameObject;
```

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста, почему, когда я второй твой способ, пытаюсь написать так: `private T Transform<T>(string Name) {
       return С.Transform<T>(Obj, Name);
    }` - получаю ошибку: **CS0314 Тип "T" не может быть использован как параметр типа "T" в универсальном типе или методе "C.Transform<T>(GameObject, string)". Нет преобразования-упаковки или преобразования параметра типа из "T" в "UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour"**
`

Comment: @FixiDens вам нужно указать ограничение для параметра `T`: `private T Transform<T>(string Name) where T : MonoBehaviour {...}`.

Comment: А как можно исправить второй вариант, так, чтобы можно было и `Transform<GameObject>` или `Transform<Transform>` возвращать, а то ошибка: **Тип "UnityEngine.GameObject" не может быть использован как параметр типа "T" в универсальном типе или методе "C.Transform<T>(string)". Нет преобразования неявной ссылки из "UnityEngine.GameObject" в "UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour".**

Comment: Это конечно хорошо все, но хочется, чтобы автоматом все было, а не самому еще потом вытаскивать разные объекты! нужно, чтобы метод работал должным образом, как и планировалось. Или это не возможно сделать?

Comment: @FixiDens я не совсем понимаю, что вы подразумеваете под "должным образом". Компоненты и Игровые объекта - это диаметрально противоположные по смыслу сущности. Невозможно написать универсальную функцию, что будет искать разные по смыслу и уж тем более по базовому типу объекты.

Comment: Так я и `Rigidbody` не могу вытащит и много других компонентов. Это тогда бессмысленная функция получается, ради одной концепции. `Должным образом` - я имею ввиду, что тип должен быть любой и чтобы я любой элемент мог вытащить из родителя. А не так, что то могу, это не могу, какой от этой функции тогда будет смысл, если она работает на половину? Проще тогда и юзать `GetComponent` из него я что угодно достать могу. Хоть `GameObject` в друг-друге =)

Comment: @FixiDens функция и должна выполнять "одну концепцию" - принцип единственной ответственности называется. Вы просили вытащить из объекта с именем компонент с переданным типом - вот вам функция `Transform<T>`, хотите получить игровый объект этого компонента - обращайтесь к свойству `gameObject`. Я просто не понимаю, в чем проблема, написать дженерик для GameObject и для Component **невозможно**.

Comment: Вы были правы, мне нужно искать `GameObject` а в ограничениях, делать `Component` а не `MonoBehavior`, в итоге найдем `GameObject<Component>`, вcе, что требовалось. `public static GameObject Transform<T>(GameObject Object, string Name) where T : Component {...}` - начинка не поменялась. Еще вопрос, а как без `<>` делать вызов, а то требует писать его, можно ли это исправить или придется отдельные методы для этого делать?

Comment: Что-то все равно не верно работает, ээээх....

Comment: @FixiDens в ответе и стоит Component. Без <> дженерик не сделать.

Comment: Я вообщем разобрался, все получилось, теперь я могу возвращать `GameObject` текущего выбранного объекта, либо его компоненты, нужно было использовать такой подход `public static T Transform<T>(GameObject Object, string Name) where T : class {.,,}` пришлось отказаться от `GetComponentsInChildren` и использовать `transform`, ну и также написал отдельный метод без генерика, в нем вернул `Transform<GameObject>(Name);` все работает, я доволен.